# Freeing object created by DLL

Tags: c++, dll, lua

My DLLs are loaded with `LoadLibrary` - can they still share the runtime or do I actually have to make sure objects are deleted in the same DLL they were allocated in?

In my example, I have a common base class that is implemented in DLL module(s), that is then mirrored by a Lua object, and Lua determines its lifespan. Thus, I need to free the object when Lua garbage collector decides to do so, and I have no way of predicting from which DLL it will be garbage collected.

I'm thinking of each DLL having a copy of the following function:

```
int ReleaseObject(lua_State* L)
{
    // object pointer is stored in field [0]
    lua_rawgeti(L, -1, 0);
    delete (Object*) lua_touserdata(L, -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Then the pointer to this function would be placed in the metatable `__gc` field, and the metatable will be used for all instances of the derived class defined in that DLL. Is this enough to guarantee safe deletion?

Comment: Certainly. You can share the reference semantics in a header that is shared by each DLL project.

Comment: I'll edit the question to include an actual example of what I'm trying to do; I just rebooted my computer by accident so my edits are lost =[

Comment: In general, [memory allocated in a DLL should be freed in that DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154939/is-it-safe-to-allocate-memory-for-buffers-on-external-dll-and-use-it-on-main-app/2154979). I'm not a C / Windows guru so I can't tell you if there's a scenario where it's safe to ditch this rule on any platform. You [could define operators new and delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085873/dll-memory-manager-mixup) to circumvent this, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (with a custom deleter calling the ReleaseObject) on the client of the dll, those can take care of the cross dll boundaries deletion correctly.

Also it's a good practice to keep your dll interface entirely `extern "C"` so that the dll can be compiled with a different c++ runtime and the names remain unmingled.
Instead of inheriting base class implementation from a dll, it would be better to export a `BaseImpl* CreateBaseImpl();
void DeleteBaseImpl(BaseImpl*);`
pair of functions and let these return a pointer to the implementation that you need. That pointer should then be fed to a smart pointer of your choice. Make BaseImpl's public interface use only primitive types (handles, numbers, pointers to such, C arrays - good; stl containers - not good: creates cpp runtime dependency)

I guess it could look like:

```
// code using LUA - unconcerned with the cross-dll nature of the implementation
...
{
    auto p = new ConcreteImpl(); // pass p to LUA as you normally would
    ...
    // when LUA wants it deleted:
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
    // probably tell LUA it was deleted
}
...
```

---

```
// BaseImpl.h - Dll Interface  header

class BaseImpl;

extern "C" BaseImpl * CreateBaseImpl();
extern "C" void DeleteBaseImpl(BaseImpl *p);
```

---

```
// Client code

#include "BaseImpl.h"

#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

#include <Windows.h>

class ConcreteImpl { // no inheritance probably necessary
{
    using namespace std;
    ...
    ConcreteImpl() 
    :   m_ptrDll( ::LoadLibraryW(L"BaseImpl.dll"), &::FreeLibrary )
    ,   m_ptrBase( nullptr, [](BaseImpl *){} )
    {
        Assert( m_ptrDll, "LoadLibraryW() failed err=0x%x", ::GetLastError() );

        auto pfnCreate = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&CreateBaseImpl)>(
            ::GetProcAddress(m_ptrDll.get(), "CreateBaseImpl") );

        auto pfnDelete = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&DeleteBaseImpl)>(
            ::GetProcAddress(m_ptrDll.get(), "DeleteBaseImpl") );

        Assert( pfnCreate && pfnDelete,
                "GetProcAddress() failed err=0x%x", ::GetLastError() );

        // use move constructor to assign new value
        m_ptrBase = decltype(m_ptrBase)( pfnCreate(), pfnDelete );

        Assert( m_ptrBase, "CreateBaseImpl returned nullptr" );
    }
    ...
    // methods that use m_ptrBase go here
    ...
    unique_ptr<
        remove_pointer<HMODULE>::type,
        decltype(&::Freelibrary)
    > m_ptrDll;

    unique_ptr<BaseImpl, decltype(&DeleteBaseImpl)> m_ptrBase;        
};
```